# Rails 3.1 I18n word declensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Let's say there is a model called "User". I want to create a form for create/update operations on that user, using form helper. In my native language declension of model name would change in this context.

Example:
Model name in common context should be "Пользовател**ь**"
Model name in form context should be "by "Пользовател**я**"

I would like to highlight that this question is not about pluralization, which is covered by many-many articles over the internet.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer:

I ended up adding the following to my locale file:

```
cs:
  helpers:
    submit:
      user:
        create: "Vytvořit Uživatele" # Create + Accusative form of User in Czech
        update: "Uložit Uživatele"   # Update + Accusative form of User in Czech
```

These are picked up by simple form, I'm not sure whether they are automatically pulled by the regular form helper or formtastic.

## Further thoughts:

So far I've failed to figure out how to reference to the accusative form when I store it in my model:

```
cs:
  models:
    user:
      one:"Uživatel"
      few:"Uživatelé"
      many:"Uživatelů"
      accusative:"Uživatele"
```

That would DRY it up quite a bit, since I would no longer need a helper scoped by model name:

```
cs:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Vytvořit <model.accusative>"
      update: "Uložit <model.accusative>"
```

Comment: This solution, however, does not scale across languages, as the same language construct can be controlled by different cases in different languages.